# Where are android sdk's 9-patch drawables?

Tags: android, android-widget, custom-controls

I am looking for android sdk's built-in 9-patch drawables, in particular the ones for `EditText` and for `Button`.

I need them because I want to change them a bit and get custom controls that take less space on the screen. I don't want to draw everything from scratch because I want my controls to look like the standard ones.

I guess it's already on my hard drive, since I have installed the sdk, but where ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in <*android install directory*>/platforms/android-<*platform version*>/data/res/drawable-mdpi